Проблема с кодировкой текста Rust
Проблема в том что вместо вывода данных с командной строки выводится это:

Как я понял, Rust неправильно декодирует текст и происходит это, пробовал использовать .decode() и .encode(), но не помогло.
Код:
use subprocess::Exec;

fn main() {
    shell("dism", "")
}
fn shell(command: &str,args: &str){
    let output = Exec::cmd(command).arg(args).capture();
    let _ = match output {
        Ok(out) => println!("\x1b[35m{}", out.stdout_str()),
        Err(error) => println!("\x1b[31m[!]ERROR: {}", error)
    };
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Перенаправьте вывод в файл и откройте в редакторе с определением кодировки. Заодно посмотрите в настройках консоли какая кодовая страница используется
